# Generic lists of <T> type - get Index of items inside collection?

Tags: c#, observablecollection, generic-list

I've created an **ObservableCollection T** method, for exporting purposes. Now I need to read all data from collection, but I also need to add values into **Dictionary<int,string>**, where **int** should be index of a property in collection.

For this I found a solution on my own:

```
     private void Get_property_values<T>(ObservableCollection<T> observableCollection)
     {
       //Dictionary where I need to update values, Items are added to It in same method
       // - before reading collection values

       Dictionary<int, string> txt_with_indx = new Dictionary<int, string>(); 
      
       txt_with_indx.Add(0,"value_to_maybe_update"); //etc...
      
       var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
       
       int indx = 0; 
       foreach (var list in observableCollection)
       {
          indx = 0;
    
          foreach (var prop in props)
          {
             string obs_txt = prop.GetValue(list, null).ToString().Trim() ?? string.Empty;
                     
             if (txt_with_indx[indx].Length < obs_txt.Length)
             {
                  txt_with_indx[indx] = obs_txt;
             }
             indx++;
         }
       }
     }
```

To get the index of a property I used variable "**indx**". Code works.

**My question: What is the proper, more elegant or even easier solution than this when working with generic lists of type T?**

Thanks for answers in advance !

Comment: Don't do a `.ToString()` in there - you have no idea the type of the property at that point so you don't know what string you'll get.

Comment: Note: in .NET, strictly-speaking, a collection-type whose name ends with `Collection` (as opposed to `List`) means its elements are not necessarily indexable. You can see this with how `IReadOnlyList` has the indexer, but `IReadOnlyCollection` does not. The `ObservableCollection<T>` type does have an indexer, but that's because it predates this collection-type naming convention (which started around .NET 4.x in 2010+).

Comment: Your code has a major bug: data added to `txt_with_indx` for the first item in `observableCollection` will be overwritten by any subsequent item with the same property name.

Comment: Your question/postying sounds like an X/Y problem: A better design would be to make-use of .NET's built-in serialization support, or use an existing serialization library and simply adapt that library's output to a Dictionary type.

Comment: @Dai, that is the point. I'm collecting longest strings in Dictionary, this code is used for Auto fit columns in Excel.